# Writing data into xls using Python Class

Tags: python, database, pandas, psycopg2, xls

```
class XlsMaker(object):
    def __init__(self,path='report'):
        self.xls = pd.ExcelWriter('%s.xlsx' %path,engine='xlsxwriter')
        df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

        # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('%s.xlsx' %path,engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

         # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
        writer.save()

    def save(self):
        print('Generating your report...')
        self.xls.save()
        self.xls.close()
        print('Done!')



#I am invoking this class like below:-
rep1 = xlsMaker("Test") 
rep1.save()
```

Xlsx file is created ,but data is not getting populated .
    When i am not using class then i am finding the xlsx created with the data.
    I want to know is there any bug in above code as i am beginner in advance python.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating two objects on the two different lines containing `pd.ExcelWriter('%s.xlsx' %path,engine='xlsxwriter')`.  One of them is a class attribute and the other is local to the initializer function.  You're calling `.save()` in the initializer on the local one.

Delete the `writer =...` line and replace all instances of `writer` with `self.xls`'